# Adding the digits of a number: code for recursion fails

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
class Solution:
    def addDigits(self, num: int) -> int:
        while num>10:
            num =  sum(int(i) for i in str(num))
            addDigits(self,num)
        
        return num
```

I am trying to use recursion.

#### Example input / expected output:

```
Input: num = 38
Output: 2
```

**Explanation:** The process is

```
38 --> 3 + 8 --> 11
11 --> 1 + 1 --> 2
```

Since 2 has only one digit, return it.

But I get errors, like:

> name 'addDigits' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `def addDigits(num):
    while num>10:
            num = addDigits( sum(int(i) for i in str(num)))
    return num `

Comment: then once it works you could decide to put it in a class

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks on your attempt:

- When deciding to go for recursion, put away the iterative solution: don't mix them. Recursion *replaces* the iteration you would otherwise do.
- When making the recursive call don't ignore what that call returns... you need it.
- `num > 10` is not exactly right: you need to distinguish whether a number has more than one digit: 10 is a number with two digits, so this should be `num >= 10`.
- `addDigits` is not a global function, but a *method*, so you need to call it as one: `self.addDigits(num)`

Taking all that into account:

```
class Solution:
    def addDigits(self, num: int) -> int:
        if num >= 10:  # no loop, and 10 should be included
            num = sum(int(i) for i in str(num))
            # call addDigits as a method:
            num = self.addDigits(num)  # and capture the returned result
        
        return num
```

A nice alternative notation for the sum expression is:

```
            num = sum(map(int, str(num)))
```